# How to conditionally convert rows to columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

df:

```
date        col1   col2
2020/10/29  A      1
2020/10/30  A      2
2020/10/28  B      10 
2020/10/29  B      11
2020/10/30  B      8
```

I need to transform it into the following DataFrame:

```
date        A   B
2020/10/28  Nan 10
2020/10/29  1   11
2020/10/30  2   8
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) as follows.

```
df = df.pivot(index="date", columns="col1", values="col2")
```

The output

```
      col1   A        B
      date      
2020/10/28  NaN     10.0
2020/10/29  1.0     11.0
2020/10/30  2.0     8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to first group by both `date` and `col1` and then `unstack` it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[{'date': '2020/10/29', 'col1': 'A', 'col2': '1'},
                        {'date': '2020/10/30', 'col1': 'A', 'col2': '2'},
                        {'date': '2020/10/28', 'col1': 'B', 'col2': '10 '},
                        {'date': '2020/10/29', 'col1': 'B', 'col2': '11'},
                        {'date': '2020/10/30', 'col1': 'B', 'col2': '8'}])
df = df.groupby(['col1', 'date'])['col2'].sum().unstack().T.reset_index()
```